# Promise returning before Lodash forEach completes

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach, promise, q

I am relatively new to working with promises and the Lodash library. When I run my code below my files are not attached to the `formData` object like I expect when the `deferred.promise` is fulfilled. As a result I'm pretty sure the `forEach` is completing before the inner `fs.writefile`'s have finished. What I am stuck with is where to place `deferred.resolve()` so that it works.

```
var formData = {}

function addAttachmentsToFormData() {

var deferred = q.defer();

_(portalOptions.attachments).forEach(function (a) {
  console.log('INDEX ::: ', idx);
  var letter = String.fromCharCode('A'.charCodeAt() + idx);

  if (idx === portalOptions.attachments.length - 1) {
    console.log('Attachments done... ');
    deferred.resolve(formData);
  } else {
    var filePath = path.join(tempDir, a.fileName);
    console.log('ATTACHMENT BUFFER ::: ', a.buffer);

    fs.writeFile(filePath, a.buffer, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
      }


      var fileKey = "attachment" + letter;

      formData["attachment" + letter] = {
        value: fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, '.tmp', a.fileName)),
        options: {
          filename: a.fileName,
          // path: filePath,
          contentType: a.contentType
        }
      }
      // });
      console.log("The attachments were saved :: ", formData);
    });
    idx++;
  }
});
return deferred.promise;
  }
```

Here is the code where the promise returns. When `console.log` here appears in console before the `console.log` for `formData` in the code above.

```
var payload =  addAttachmentsToFormData(portalOptions, options)
      .then( function (result) {
        console.log('REQUEST PAYLOAD READY ', result);
        sendRequest(result)

      });
```

If anyone can point out what I am doing wrong I'd appreciate the guidance. Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I've rearranged my code and it seems to be going in the right direction. However, my final `deferred.promise` is not outputting the `formData` as it should in the `console.log`.  I am still unsure as to how to promisify my `fs.writeFile` block so that the files will be written and the respective properties added to the `formData` object before the final promise is return.

As the code is below, the `console.log` of `DATA 1` logs the `formData` perfectly whereas the `console.log` of `DATA 2` does not. Again any help to get this working is greatly appreciated!

```
  function testIterate() {
    return q.all(_.map(params.attachments, function (a) {

      var deferred = q.defer();

      var filePath = path.join(tempDir, a.fileName);
      //console.log('ATTACHMENT BUFFER ::: ', a.buffer);

      fs.writeFile(filePath, a.buffer, function (err) {
        if (err) {
          // error
        }

        // Iterate letters to create unique keys for each attachment
        var letter = String.fromCharCode('A'.charCodeAt() + idx);

        var fileKey = "attachment" + letter;

        deferred.resolve(
          formData[fileKey] = {
            value: fs.createReadStream(filePath),
            options: {
              filename: a.fileName,
              //path: filePath,
              contentType: a.contentType
            }
          }
        );

        console.log('THIS IS THE FORM DATA 1 :: ', formData);
        // Increment to assign unique letter to next attachment key
        idx++;
      });

      return deferred.promise;


    })).then(function (results) {
      console.log('THIS IS THE FORM DATA 2 :: ', results);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Yes, you're resolving the promise in the last iteration of the `forEach`. There's no attempt to wait for the asynchronous operations.

Comment: Thanks for response. Yes, I had a feeling it is the `resolve` that is the issue. I'm just not sure where I should `resolve` to make it work.

Comment: Don't use deferreds and `resolve` at all. [Promisfy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) `fs.writeFile`, then use `_.map` and `q.all`.

Comment: `results` is an array of the objects you called `resolve` with. Just log `formData` instead and ignore the callback parameter.

Comment: Thanks. That seems to have solved the main issue with logging the data correctly.